# Rotate only text not whole canvas

Tags: android, drawing

I'm trying to draw text and draw bitmap via canvas, I want to rotate only text but whole canvas is rotating, any ideas?

```
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, conf);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

    Paint color = new Paint();
    color.setTextSize(35);
    color.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    color.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(drawable.getBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawText("Test", 30, 30, color);
    return bmp;
```

I have google map and marker method setRotation rotates bmp

Comment: You are drawing the both Bitmap and Text on Google Maps Canvas or on your own Custom View's Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `canvas.save()` before you apply your transformation to the `Canvas`. When you are done drawing your text you call `canvas.restore()`. Calling `restore()` returns the `Canvas` to the state it had at the time you called `save()`.

Comment: I need to draw text rotated, dont wont to rotate canvas, rotate text only